# Axis breaks in ggplot histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Is there a way to make breaks in my histogram axis if I have values much larger from the rest of my data?

For example using the following dummy data to make a ggplot histogram:

```
test_data <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,100,100,50,5000)

df = data.frame(test_data)

ggplot(df, aes(test_data))+geom_histogram()
```

Yields a histogram with a large gap[image]

I would love for the x-axis to have bins from 0 to 1000 then a cut then continue from 4000 on. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

The linked "duplicate" has broken images and even after trying out their suggestions, I did not achieve what I want. I tried
`geom_histogram(breaks=c(seq(1, 100, by=1),seq(200,1000,by=100), seq(2000,5000, by=1000))` But this gives huge, wide bars and that is not what I want.

Comment: I think you can do this with `plotrix` or `ggplot` is a must?

Comment: no i am flexible

Comment: working on it, sir

Comment: I was wrong ... having investigated I couldn't find any way of doing this. Sorry. If I'll find something, will post an answer.

Comment: The linked "duplicate" has broken images and even after trying out their suggestions, I did not achieve what I want.

Comment: All the images in the linked question work fine for me. You should make sure you don't have a content filter breaking them. That said, I tend to agree it is not a duplicate. I don't have an answer though, I'm just a reviewer.